# what does state=installed mean in ansible apt?

Tags: ansible

What does `state=installed` mean in ansible apt?

```
- name: Install Node.js
  apt:
    pkg:
      - nodejs
    state: installed
    update_cache: yes
```

It is not mentioned in the docs nor elsewhere.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we look into the [code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/packaging/os/apt.py#L785):

```
# Deal with deprecated aliases
if p['state'] == 'installed':
    p['state'] = 'present'
if p['state'] == 'removed':
    p['state'] = 'absent'
```

`installed` is a deprecated form of `present`,
`removed` is a deprecated form of `absent`.

Comment: Thanks, Konstantin ;)